# Transform a complex array from a dql query to a simple one returning just selected entries

Tags: php, sql, arrays, symfony, doctrine

I have written a dql query:

```
$emails = $manager->createQuery('SELECT (u.email) as email FROM App\Entity\User u')->getResult();
```

That returns:

[image: Array]

I would like to transform it in a simple array who'll list directly the emails like:

```
$emails = ["email1", "email2", "email3", "email4" ...];
```

Does anyone could help me with that?.

Answer (score 2):

```
$emails = $manager->createQuery('SELECT (u.email) as email FROM App\Entity\User u')->getResult();
$emails = array_column($emails, 'email');
```

Comment: Feel free to __accept__ the answer if it solves your problem.